# Nesting a for loop to print seven elements of an array per line

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that inserts the powers of 2, all the way up to 2^2000, to an array and then prints them all out 7 numbers on a line. I've figured everything out so it works but I feel like there's a better and cleaner way of doing this... particularly around the nested for loop area. I use y-- to decrement the main for-loop but I feel like this isn't a great fit.  Code:

```
public class powers {

   public static void main(String[] args){
      long arr[] = new long[2000];

      for (int x=0; x<2000; x++){
         arr[x] = (long) Math.pow(2, x);
       }


      for (int y=0; y<14;y++) {
         for (int z=0; z<7; z++) {
            System.out.print(arr[y++] + " ");
         }
         y--; // Decrement y by 1 so that it doesn't get double incremented when top for loop interates
         System.out.println(); // Print a blank line after seven numbers have been on a line
      }

      }

}
```

Comment: I looked it up - long is only 64 bits, so the answer is certainly not.

Comment: you would need java.math.BigInteger for this...

Comment: yeah, not too worried about this right now but thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i ++) {
  System.out.print(arr[i]); // note it's not println
  if (i % 7 == 6) { // this will be true after every 7th element
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is more efficient because it prints it out as it goes.  You cut out the cost of having to iterate through them all again by doing it this way.  Also, as mentioned in the comments up top, a long can't store the values in the upper region of these powers.

```
public class powers {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        long arr[] = new long[2000];

        for(int x=0; x<2000; x++){

            arr[x] = (long) Math.pow(2, x);

            System.out.print(arr[x] + " ");

            if(x%7==6)
                System.out.println();

        }

        //because your loop doesn't end on a 7th element, I add the following:
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Comment: your output will start with a blank line and won't end with \r\n

Comment: You say that like it's a bad thing.  I'll fix it, just to make you happy.  Give me a moment.

Comment: It seems it is not what he requires, so it is a bad think.. I am not sure about the 'end with \r\n' (if it is needed or not) but it certainly shouldn't stat with a blank line.

Comment: If he doesn't care about the last one, why should he care about the first? ;)  I updated it anyway.